# Java hashing function to return int that does not exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, hash

I need a hash function to return an int under the MAX_VALUE limit; as of now, I am receiving very large longs through the methods I have tried, given in the link below.
[My current methods](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)

That was my question, since I implemented a hashtable with RandomAccesFile and need to get to position the whole seek to register or read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**
The methods you used were for returning longs. The method you should use is String.hashCode() if you don't need hashing for security purposes. Make sure to cast an integer as a String through String.valueOf(int) before hashing it, since you said you want to hash ints as well.

`int hash = String.valueOf(input).hashCode();`

**2**
Edit: Added MD5 info after OP requested in comment

I have a class that can take an input String, process it through MD5, and convert it to a long, though I don't know how to convert it to an int. What you can do is return the long, and truncate it to only 10 characters for an int. Here is the class:

```
import java.security.*;

public class HX {

  final String seed;
  final MessageDigest md;
  final long hash;

  public HX(String s) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

   seed = s;
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    hash = computeHash();
  }

  public long getHash() {
    return hash;
  }

  public long computeHash() {
    md.reset();
    final byte[] digest = md.digest(seed.getBytes());
    return (computeHash(digest, 0) ^ computeHash(digest, 8));
  }

  private static final long computeHash(final byte[] array, final int offset) {
    long value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
       value = ((value << 8) | (array[offset+i] & 0xFF));
    }
    return value;
   }
}
```

It could still exceed the MAX_VALUE after truncation, however, so if that's the case, you'd need to truncate it an int of length 9.

```
long longHash = 0;
try {
     HX h = new HX(seed);
     longHash = h.getHash();
} catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
  int hash = Integer.parseInt(longHash.substring(0,9));
} catch(Exception e) {
  int hash = Integer.parseInt(longHash.substring(0,8));
}
```

**3**
Another alternative is a "better hash" with reduced collisions, at least with regards to dictionary words.

```
public static int hash(String s) {
  int hash = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      hash = 257*hash + s.charAt(i);
  }
  return h;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, eh tested and it works, but I try to find the best solutions to subtract the number of collisions

Comment: If you are worried about collisions, then methods like MD5 and SHA1 will do a much better job as compared to String.hashCode(). However, for security purposes, MD5 is essentially considered broken due to possible collisions, but for rudimentary purposes it should do the job.

Comment: excuse me but may return an integer with the MD5 and SHA1 functions? as this is done?

Comment: That was my question, since I implemented a hashtable with RandomAccesFile and need to get to position the whole seek to register or read

Comment: No you cannot return an int with these functions directly. See my edit above. My method may seem elaborate, but it should not take that much time to implement, especially since I gave you the class already.

Comment: @KartikChughヅ "their characters are made of 0-9 and a-f " That's not at all the issue. An MD5 hash *is* an integer, just wider than a 32-bit int, and *traditionally* printed for human consumption in base 16. It can, of course, be truncated to 32 bits. The base in which it is typically displayed is irrelevant.

Comment: That's correct actually; how can I edit that part of my comment out so as to not mislead anyone?

Comment: @KartikChughヅ You unfortunately can't; comments can only be edited for   five minutes. I strongly suggest deleting the comment and adding the content to your answer; comments are ephemeral and should not be used for important content.

Comment: Also, to get an int rather than a long from the MD5 hash, you can simply xor the two halves of that long together using `(int)((hash>>>32 & 0xffffL) ^ (hash>>>32 & 0xffffL))` (code not tested, but should be the correct idea)